# Use the bisection method to find solutions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Use the bisection method to find solutions accurate to within `10^−4` on the interval `[−5, 5]` of the following functions:
>
> ```
> f(x)= x^5-10x^3-4
> ```

This is my code:

```
function sol=bisect(fn,a,b,tol)

%Bisection method for the Nonlinear Function
fa=feval(fn,a);fb=feval(fn,b);
if fa*fb>0;fprintf('Endpoints have same sign')
   return
end
k=0;
while abs (b - a)>tol
   c =(a+b)/2;
   fc=feval(fn,c);
   if fa*fc < 0; b=c; else a = c; 
       k=k+1;
   end
end
sol=(a+b)/2;
```

When I run the program, I do:

```
a= -5
b=5
fn =  x^5-10x^3-4
```

But the last line returns an error:

> undefined function or  variable x

Answer (score 1):

to define an equation that can be evaluated by `feval`, you need to define as a function.

Try defining `fn` as `fn=@(x)(x^5-10x^3-4)`. 
This way you can use `feval(fn,3)`.

Comment: Is the code " fn=@(x)(^5-10x^3-4) " right? I followed your answer, but there was an error on my matlab. I changed the code like  " fn=@(x)(x^5-10*x^3-4) ". and It worked. I am confused if it is my matlab's problem or not.

Comment: @김갑수 no, I made a typo! you are rigth.